# Rails 3 - Partial Not Rendering

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

In my view I have the following:

```
<div class="subject edit">
<%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @subject.id}) do |f| %>

<%= render(:partial => "form", :locals => {:f => f}) %>

<div class="form-buttons">
    <%= submit_tag("Update Subject") %>
</div>


<% end %>
```

In the same folder I have created a partial (_form.html.erb). But for some reason it is not rendered.

_form.html.erb:

```
<table summary="Subject form fields">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:position) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Visible?</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:visible) %></td>
    </tr>
```

I'm running rails 3.2.7. Can some see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it not rendering with some error or is the partial not being shown?

Comment: It's just not shown. As if I had forgotten the '=' in the <%= %>

Comment: Ahh shoot! I restarted server and it's working! Sorry

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Server restart also did not fix the issue. What other things shall I look for. Server log shows "Rendered partial_name.html.erb", but I cant see anything on UI. I have also checked for "<%= render" instead of "<% render".

Comment: If server log shows as partial is rendered but you cannot see it in UI, replace the <%= render "partial" %> with the code in the partial and try again. This will test whether your code is working properly, independent of the partial rendering.

Answer (score 0):

A server reset fixed the issue. Doh!